# Small Bug in Edit Summary TextBox

Tags: bug

When i click on the "Edit Summary" textbox some previous suggestions pop up, and that's fine, but when I select one of them the hint on the textbox doesn't clear and my text and hint are both shown until I press a key:

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

I'm using Waterfox (64-bit equivalent of Firefox) version 32 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Are you sure this is an SO issue, rather than a browser issue? Also, note that it's *"grammar"* (there's a certain irony to getting this wrong!)

Comment: I Can't test that in another browser because i don't have any prevues suggestion on them and YES that's funny :| but my primary language isn't English give me a break will you :)

Comment: You are right, I see the same in Firefox 38.0.5 on my Macbook with OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. I wanted to make a screenshot of it, but once I hit the shortkey for that, a key is pressed and the problem is gone.

Comment: Yes i used a recording software for the screenshot

Comment: @jonrsharpe Look at the source, they use a manipulated span instead of the HTML5 placeholder attribute. I think the event isn't fired when you click on the previously used text, only when you paste, type a text, or focus out the input.