# Bug in Edit Summary field while editing question

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

There is a bug in Edit Summary field while editing question, **this bug only occurs while we use autocomplete by double clicking the input field**.

**Please refer images below:**

While selecting autocomplete text the placeholder text is not disappearing as shown in image below.

[image: Bug image 1]

After we select the autocomplete suggestion also the placeholder text is not been replaced with user input as shown in image below:

[image]

**NOTE:** while typing this question i came across [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297418/small-bug-in-edit-summary-textbox)  **asked Jun 21 '15 at 8:00**.
Is the issue has not been resolved still?

**Browser used:** Google chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 m

Comment: I sometimes get this too on newish FF. I think it also happens when you paste something into that box.

Comment: no this is happening when we use autocomplete suggestion, ie when we double click in the field we get autocomplete history from browser. it don't happen when we paste. i tried.

Comment: For me, It does happen when I paste into the box, _as well as when I use the autocomplete_.. Don't know why its different for you, maybe different browser / OS / version or something.

Comment: May be, which os and browser are you using.

Comment: Firefox on Linux.

Comment: yeah, we skipped that view while we `placeholder`d the rest of the inputs.. the thing is, that's the most hit view, that autofocuses the title field on the ask page, and `placeholder` behavior is differs between browsers. We really want to show the overlay hint, there even when the title input has focus... Making it a placeholder is probably going to be OK on the edit summary input...

Comment: @m0sa do you mean to say it is not a bug?  like http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31peUDbGA5L.jpg .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed with the latest build, we're now using placeholders on all post editing forms.

Comment: yes, its fixed !